# Could you show me some very easy mate in 20?

Tags: checkmate, problems, elementary-mates

I am looking for some puzzles where there is a forced mate in as many moves as possible (ideally 20 or more). Yet the puzzles need to be as easy as possible!

You will probably need to find some puzzles where the defending side has a lot of spite checks to delay the mate.

.

**Edit :**

I just made a very easy mate in approximately 23. White to move:

[image]

It's really really easy since Black can do nothing. But it doesn't totally satisfies me since the position is of course not legal...

Comment: This seems like a broad topic, to be covered in a single answer...

Comment: This problem is for people who like playing draught more than chess...

Comment: @David: No. 1.Bf1 (only move) Bg1+ 2.Kg2. The Black Bishop will harass the White King with checks, delaying the checkmate. The only piece that Black can move is the Black Bishop that is initially on e3. The White King can never take the Black Bishop since it would be stalemate. The White King is forced to block the path of the h1 White Bishop for 6 moves: Kg2-f1-e2-d1-c2-b1. So it's a mate in 17+6 = 23 moves if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I present unto you a superbly easy mate in 21 that I found the other day in the [Matplus.net forums.](http://matplus.net/start.php?px=1558655710&app=forum&act=posts&fid=xshown&tid=1610) Give it a try!

```
[Title "Filip Bondarenko, Feenschach 1960, Mate In 21"]
[FEN "8/7Q/2r1p3/2rkr3/2rrr2Q/7K/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

This is a mate in 24 that I quite like. You can view the solution in [Yet Another Chess Problem Database.](https://www.yacpdb.org/#442276)

```
[Title "Martin Hoffmann & Franz Lutsenberger, Schach-Almanach 1977-1978, Mate In 24"]
[FEN "8/7p/6pP/5pP1/pK2pP2/1pBpP3/pn1N4/k7 w - - 0 1"]
```

Finally, just for fun, here is a legal version of @Fate‘s idea that I have created solely for this answer.

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 8/16/2019, Mate In 20"]
[FEN "6bB/3p1pB1/2pP1Ppr/2P3P1/2p5/2P3p1/5pPk/5Kbr w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 9):

There are many:

```
     [Title "Mate in 20"]
 [FEN "3K1B2/1p6/pp6/rk2N3/b1p5/1pP5/1P2P3/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

You should search puzzles from the 1900. It was a golden era for chess puzzles. I found a mate in 63 some days ago.

Chessmaster also has a nice collection of interesting(and long) puzzles. There are many sites where you can sort puzzles according to difficulty and turns to mate, but I can't remember any atm.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easy mate in 20 with a unique solution
(which becomes a very easy mate in 19 after the first move):

```
[Title "Noam D. Elkies, Chess Stack Exchange 2020"]
[FEN "6bn/p4p1k/p4Ppp/p7/p3K1P1/P4N2/1P6/7n w - - 0 1"]
```